# Installing ESLint locally doesn't work

Tags: javascript, eslint

If I install ESLint globally I can use it, but if I uninstall the global ESLint and install it only inside the project folder with:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

And then run eslint -v, it says command not found.

Do I need to install ESLint also globally if I want to use it only in my project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing it locally will install it under the `node_modules` directory, which will not be in the PATH your system searches for executables.

Run it with `npx`, which is distributed with recent versions of `npm`.

```
npx eslint -v
```

Comment: Do I need to install it also globally? Because after running npx eslint -v, if I run eslint script.js, I still get command not found error.

Comment: No. You run `npx eslint` instead of plain `eslint`.

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To use it locally, ensure you have eslint installed:

`npm install --save-dev eslint`

The in your project folder run:

`./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`

Answer (score 0):

You only installed it locally, so you can only run it via `./node_modules/.bin/eslint -v`.
To install it globally do it like this: `npm install --global esint --save-dev`. Maybe you need sudo/root rights.

Comment: You've changed your answer but it's still bad advice. Don't install this globally and definitely don't ever install anything globally with sudo.

Comment: I don't think installing it globally is bad advice, it has some flaws, but there are reasons to do it. 
It's bad because of security reasons (npm process runs as root, a evil dependency can possibly misuse it), it can make problems with your package manager and because removing the project folder doesn't also wipe the dependencies.
But if you want eslint in your PATH, it's fine. But you should think about the flaws before.
EDIT: Yeah, maybe it's bad advice. Use npx, maybe use pnpm if you don't want to have the same dependency bloat your hdd multiple times.

Comment: I disagree for a few major reasons: 1) it's unnecessary in an era with `npx`; 2) it's a security risk in that you end up with zombie packages; and 3) it's a MAJOR security risk if you end up using `sudo`. Basically, it's a concern that was addressed by `npx`. There's just no need to assume the added risk.

Comment: I agree its better local than global. But npx installs EVERY TIME the dependencies, and you already have it locally. Npm-run would solve this, but apparently eslint doesnt get installed in node_modules/bin... geez!

Answer (score 0):

for me it works with `npx`. so, commands will be something below (may be it will work for you with `npm`)

> npx eslint --fix
> npx eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx
> npx eslint --fix . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx